# How to use Stripe with React and Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stripe-payments

So I'm using firebase as my database and hosting service and I've written the application in React.

Now I'm trying to add Stripe to the application so I can charge customers. But there is an issue, Stripe seems to need a separate server, which is a bit of an issue because I'm using Firebase.

I've read the documentation (here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/use-cases/payments) and watched the videos from firebase (here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrLTF4QdRrM and here - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BrLTF4QdRrM) and I'm still lost.

I have no idea where I'm meant to include the Stripe Publishable Key and I've worked myself into such a knot I'm going to have to spend the next few hours undoing the last few hours of effort.

If you can point me in the direction of a simple guide or just tell me where the Publishable Key needs to go, that would be hugely helpful!

This may confuse more than help but here is the code that I've created to create a stripe customer and stripe charge etc.

```
mport * as stripe from "stripe";
import * as functions from "firebase";
import getFirestoreDb from "../firebase/firestore/getFirestoreDb";


// import {firestore} from "@firebase/firestore/dist/packages/firestore/test/util/api_helpers";
// const admin = require('firebase-admin');
// admin.initializeApp();


// const logging = require('@google-cloud/logging')();
// const currency = functions.config().stripe.currency || 'USD';

const db = getFirestoreDb();

//START CUSTOMER CHARGE //
// Charge the Stripe customer whenever an amount is created in Cloud Firestore

export const createStripeCharge = functions.firestore
  .document('stripe_customers/{userId}/charges/{autoId}')
  .onCreate(async ( snap, context) => {
    const val = snap.data();
    try {
      //Look up the Stripe customer id written in createStripeCustomer
      const snapshot = await
        db.collection('stripe_customers')
        .doc(context.params.userId).get();
      const snapval = snapshot.data();
      const customer = snapval.customer_id;

      // Create a charge using the pushId as the idempotency key
      // protecting against double charges
      const amount = val.amount;
      const idempotencyKey = context.params.id;
      const currency = "USD";
      const charge = {amount, currency, customer};
      if (val.source !== null) {
        charge.source = val.source;
      }
      // setSourceOrDefault(charge, snap.data().source)
      const response = await stripe.charges.create(charge, {idempotency_key: idempotencyKey} );
      //if the result is successful, write it back to the database
      return snap.ref.set(response, {merge:true});
    } catch(error)  {
      // We want to capture errors and render them in a user-friendly way, while
      // still logging an exception with StackDriver
      await snap.ref.set({error: userFacingMessage(error)}, {merge:true});
      // return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
    }
  });

// END CUSTOMER CHARGE //

// When a user is created, register them with Stripe
export const createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
  return db.collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: customer.id});
});

// Add a payment source (card) for a user by writing a stripe payment source token to Cloud Firestore
export const addPaymentSource = functions.firestore.document('/stripe_customers/{userId}/tokens/{pushId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
  const source = snap.data();
  const token = source.token;
  if (source === null){
    return null;
  }

  try {
    const snapshot = await db.collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).get();
    const customer =  snapshot.data().customer_id;
    const response = await stripe.customers.createSource(customer, {source: token});
    return db.collection('stripe_customers').doc(context.params.userId).collection("sources").doc(response.fingerprint).set(response, {merge: true});
  } catch (error) {
    await snap.ref.set({'error':userFacingMessage(error)},{merge:true});
    // return reportError(error, {user: context.params.userId});
  }
});

// When a user deletes their account, clean up after them
export const cleanupUser = functions.auth.user().onDelete(async (user) => {
  const snapshot = await db.collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).get();
  const customer = snapshot.data();
  await stripe.customers.del(customer.customer_id);
  return db.collection('stripe_customers').doc(user.uid).delete();
});

// To keep on top of errors, we should raise a verbose error report with Stackdriver rather
// than simply relying on console.error. This will calculate users affected + send you email
// alerts, if you've opted into receiving them.
// // [START reporterror]
// function reportError(err, context = {}) {
//   // This is the name of the StackDriver log stream that will receive the log
//   // entry. This name can be any valid log stream name, but must contain "err"
//   // in order for the error to be picked up by StackDriver Error Reporting.
//   const logName = 'errors';
//   const log = logging.log(logName);
//
//   // https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/api/ref_v2beta1/rest/v2beta1/MonitoredResource
//   const metadata = {
//     resource: {
//       type: 'cloud_function',
//       labels: {function_name: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME},
//     },
//   };
//
//   // https://cloud.google.com/error-reporting/reference/rest/v1beta1/ErrorEvent
//   const errorEvent = {
//     message: err.stack,
//     serviceContext: {
//       service: process.env.FUNCTION_NAME,
//       resourceType: 'cloud_function',
//     },
//     context: context,
//   };
//
//   // Write the error log entry
//   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
//     log.write(log.entry(metadata, errorEvent), (error) => {
//       if (error) {
//         return reject(error);
//       }
//       return resolve();
//     });
//   });
// }
// [END report error]


function userFacingMessage(error) {
  return error.type ? error.message : 'An error has occurred, developers have been alerted';
}

stripe.setPublishableKey("STRIPE_KEY");
```

Comment: Hey Rory! The Publishable key is set on the client for working with Stripe.js to tokenize payment details. In addPaymentSource that token you see is likely the token that was created on the client using stripe.createToken or similar to convert raw card details into a reference token. You should only need to set your secret key in the firebase function, then the publishable key in React.

Comment: Hmm, I've come to the conclusion that my issue may be with firebase functions rather than with stripe itself. I'm slamming into this error:  functions: Cannot set property config of #<Object> which has only a getter.

Any suggestions on how I can go about solving this?

Comment: That's not much to go on. Are you able to add some more logging? #<Object> could be anything.

Comment: Yup, thats one of my issues. And no, I'm not sure how I would do that to be honest.

Comment: Can you share the full output of the error, which line its failing on, what you've tried? Adding `console.log("I'm here line 4")` in a bunch of places can be useful to tell where the code fails and to test your assumptions.

Comment: emulators: Starting emulators: functions
hub: emulator hub started at http://localhost:4400
functions: functions emulator started at http://localhost:5001
functions: Watching "/Users/mac/WebstormProjects/Olas/functions" for Cloud Functions...
functions: Cannot set property config of #<Object> which has only a getter
Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
functions: Cannot set property config of #<Object> which has only a getter
Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215434/discussion-between-rory-odoherty-and-cjav-dev).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the publishable key on the client side.

For example, using React Native and tipsi-stripe (stripe client sdk) you can do as following:

```
import stripe from 'tipsi-stripe'

stripe.setOptions({
    publishableKey: 'YOUR-PUBLISHABLE-KEY',
})
```

You just need to initialize the stripe client sdk you are using with your publishableKey.